# Numpy iterating over 3d vector array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, iteration

Im trying to iterate over a Numpy Array that contains 3d numpy arrays (3d vectors) inside it.
Something like this:

```
import numpy as np


Matrix = np.zeros(shape=(10, 3))
# => [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    ...
    [0,0,0]
]
```

I need to iterate over it, getting each 3d Vector.
In pseudo code:

```
for vector in Matrix
    print vector #=> [0,0,0]
```

Is there any Numpy native way of doing this? 
What is the fastest way of doing this?

Thanks!

Fran

Comment: Terminology note: a 3D numpy array is one whose shape has 3 elements. For example, `np.zeros([3, 4, 5])` would be a 3D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudocode is only missing a colon:

```
for vector in matrix:
    print vector
```

That said, you will generally want to avoid explicit iteration over a NumPy array. Take advantage of broadcasted operations and NumPy built-in functions as much as possible; it moves the loops into C instead of interpreted Python, and it tends to produce shorter code, too.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer.

Is there any Numpy way of doing this? Like for example with nditer?

Comment: @plant: nditer wouldn't simplify your code or make it run faster; it'd just be unnecessary complication. The NumPy way of doing it would be to not use a loop at all and figure out how to get broadcasting and built-in functions to do the job, but if you really want a loop, this is how you would do it.

Comment: That's a very good clear question. So i'll look into broadcasting. Thanks!